# How to pass property value to IMvxCommand from .axml in Xamarin.Android MVVMCross

Tags: android, xamarin, data-binding, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I am trying to pass property value to to `IMvxCommand` from the binding implemented in XML

Here is the XML binding

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button Label"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:letterSpacing=".08"
        android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.12"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        card_view:MvxBind="Click ItemSelectedCommand , CommandParameter = Location.Id; Typeface StringToFont('Effra_Rg')"/>
```

And below is the command

I am always getting value as a `String` "Location.Id" into `param`.

am I doing anything wrong here or is there any alternative to achieve this.

**Edit 1 :**

Location Model

```
 public class Location
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("latitude")]
    public double Latitude { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("longitude")]
    public double Longitude { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("location")]
    public LocationDetail LocationDetail { get; set; }
}
```

Bellow is the view model:

```
public class GenericLocationViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    public Location Location { get; set; }

    public LocationExtension LocationExtension { get; set; }
    private MainViewModel _mainViewModel;
    private readonly IMvxNavigationService _navigationService;

    public GenericLocationViewModel(Location location, IMvxNavigationService navigationService, LocationType locationType = LocationType.UrgentCare)
    {
        Location = location;
        LocationExtension = new LocationExtension(location, locationType);
        _navigationService = navigationService ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(navigationService));
        _mainViewModel = new MainViewModel(_navigationService);
    }

    public IMvxCommand ItemSelectedCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new MvxCommand<String>(async param =>
            {
                if (param==null) // Here getting value as "Location.Id" but I am expecting the value of Id from Location model.
                {
                    //Implementation.
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `Location.Id`?

Comment: Location is Model object  in my MvxViewModel and Id is one the property of that model

Comment: Add your Model and ViewModel code that will make it easier

Comment: We don't have support for that in AXML bindings right now. So you can't. You could define your binding in your code behind for that particular binding if you really need it. But why not just look at the Item you select instead?